# A question on circle

Tags: geometry, circles

I was solving sample maths paper and came through this question:-

**If a ball is dropped on ice having a diameter of $24cm$ and fill inside with depth of $8cm$, find the radius of the circle drawn over ice if the ball is pull outside ?**

I was not able to understand the question. Please help.

**Edit**

My solution:-

[image: ://i.stack.imgur.com/k7FLh.png]

$\text{Hypotenuse} = 12$

$\text{Height} = 4 cm$

So $(\text{Base})^2 = 12^2 - 4^2 = 128$

Is it correct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Draw a picture and use the Pythagorean theorem.

**Answer** The radius: $8\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Please provide more guidance. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Vivek, can you see a right angled triangle there? Hint: one its sides is the radius of the circle you are interested in.

Comment: Draw also the center of this circle and its orthogonal projection on the ice's surface and try to find a right triangle.

Comment: @VivekSadh This is a really good hint. If you are stuck, you're going to have to tell us where.

Comment: Thanks Sami and Jyrki for giving excellent hint :)

Comment: @VivekSadh You're welcome:)

Answer (score 0):

My solution:-

[image: ://i.stack.imgur.com/k7FLh.png]

Hypo = 12

Height = 4 cm

So Base^2 = 12^2 - 4^2 = 128

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Yes, it is correct.